# applicationDidEnterBackground: and time to write on a database

Tags: ios, database, background

When the application terminates, I write data on a database.

As from iOS 4 applicationWillTerminate: isn't called, I've put the same saving code both in applicationDidEnterBackground: and applicationWillTerminate:

I read that the task performed in applicationDidEnterBackground: has to take a few time.

So, if the writing on the db takes more, how could I manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get 5 seconds to perform any saving etc in the applicationDidEnterBackground: method.

If you need more than 5 seconds there is this UIApplication method to request a background thread which will allow for more time to do whatever you need:

```
- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler
```

Here is Apple's example code for this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12

Comment: There isn't the same problem with applicationWillTerminate, is it?

Comment: It's basically the same issue for both methods. Apple expect your app to be fully saved in the background so it can be purged when RAM is required. You'll find that applicationWillTerminate is almost never called on iOS 4 with a device >= 3GS. Think of backgrounding as the app saving and closing, and if you are resumed from RAM then it's a bonus.

Comment: I'm a little confused :) in the case of iOS4 and superior, I could use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to be sure that the saving on DB is completed. In the case of iOS<4? in that case applicationWillTerminate is called and I do the db saving also there. How can I be sure that the saving is completed?

Comment: Ah well in that case you're kinda screwed. Pre iOS4 you have to get it done in the allotted time. I'm not 100% certain it was 5 seconds for pre iOS4 but you had no choice but to make it fit. The best bet if you must exceed the time given is to try to save before you get exited. 5 seconds is quite some time, mind you.